# Prevent scrolling of non fixed element when you reach the end of fixed element

Tags: css, scroll

I have an odd problem in which I am not sure how to fix. I have a fixed sidebar on the left and content on the right. When you reach the bottom of the fixed sidebar, the content on the right starts to scroll. I want to prevent that from happening. I have started a fiddle to show. Any suggestions?

```
.menu {
position: fixed;
top: 0;
bottom: 10px;
width: 200px;
background: #eee;
margin: 10px;
overflow: scroll;
}
.content {
background: #ddd;
margin-left: 220px;
}
```

[jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/zz8dsL0h/)

Comment: I think that's normal behaviour. The mouse is still over the body/page and so what **can** continue to scroll...does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't mind scrollbars only showing on hover you can disable/enable them on hover. When an element's scrollbars are hidden, the element will not scroll.

Javascript:

```
var menu = document.querySelector('.menu');
var content = document.querySelector('.content');
var body = document.querySelector('body');
menu.addEventListener('mouseenter', function (event) {
    menu.style['overflow'] = 'auto';
    menu.style['padding-right'] = '0px';
});
menu.addEventListener('mouseleave', function (event) {
    menu.style['overflow'] = 'hidden';
    menu.style['padding-right'] = '17px';
});

content.addEventListener('mouseenter', function (event) {
    body.style['overflow'] = 'auto';
    body.style['padding-right'] = '0px';
});
content.addEventListener('mouseleave', function (event) {
    body.style['overflow'] = 'hidden';
    body.style['padding-right'] = '17px';
});
```

Also add `box-sizing: borderbox` to `menu`'s style, and apply the default hidden style to `menu` and `body`:

```
.menu, body {
    overflow: hidden;
    padding-right: 17px;
}
```

<kbd>[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wdwcdc95/)</kbd>

Comment: Yep. This did the trick, was hoping to not use js, but it works.